# Java apache commons lang3 update to 3.12.0 not found in IntelliJ Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package, apache-commons-lang3

This is my first time using Maven and I want to make the Apache commons lang3 a dependency.

When I added it to the pom.xml file, originally as version 3.1, Intellij comes up with the message:

[image]

I looked on the website and it is in fact now on a stable version of 3.12.0, and IntelliJ/Maven knows this, which is why it is suggested. So when I change it to 3.12.0, it comes up saying:

[image]

So it both somehow knows that there is a updated version, but doesn't have the ability to update it? Is there something I am missing that I need to do? As I said I haven't used Maven before, so I don't know if there is something else I need to add. For reference all I did was added Maven as a framework support and then added the above  tags below the properties tag.

As an additional question, my project doesn't seem to have added lang3 (3.1) as I tried to import it to a class to use it and it cannot be found, what else do I need to do to be able to use lang3 in my project?

Comment: did you run maven update from your intelliJ?

Comment: Try to click on `Reload all Maven projects` in Maven tool window. If the problem remains check if `/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar` exists in your .m2 directory. If not, try to close the IDE, delete the .m2 directory and re-import the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, I hadn't reloaded the Maven project like I thought, so it is all working now, thank you!

[image: Reload Maven Project]